# Writing a rewrite condition in .htaccess to remove all characters until the first "-" in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My former URL-structure was

https://www.domain.de/category/category/.../product-productID

The new URL-structure is:

https://www.domain.de/category/category/.../product

I need to redirect the old URL to the new ones and how to write a rewrite condition that basically reads the URL backwards and removes all characters up to the first "-".

Do you have any idea how to get this done or if it is even possible that way?

Thanks

Comment: does the new URI is the same & correct path so no need to go to old path internally ?

Comment: Yes. The only thing that changes is the removal of the productID

Comment: Ok , then when URI category/category/.../product , does that will go correct if productID not in request , i mean does productID fixed to all previous structure or not?

Comment: It was fixed to product-pages. Other pages like category-pages or landing pages dont have it

Answer (score 0):

Try this for specific mentioned URI :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\-productID$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

But ,if you want to make it for all other pages as well do this only :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\-[a-zA-Z]+$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```